# Laravel redirect with errors on validation

Tags: ajax, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I really need your help!

I have a web-app with multiple nav-tabs which content is loaded by the attribute "data-url". I need to do this because I have a big amount of data displayed in each tab and I don't want to make a query for every tab even when it's not displayed.
So I load the content just when the tab is displayed.
In each tab, depending on the user role, I load the requested data, a message saying that you can't see the data, a message that says the data are not added or a button that open a modal to insert that data.

For example:

```
<li class="nav-item" data-url="/{{$document->progressive_number}}/getInfo" data-id="document_info">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#document_info">Document info</a>
</li>


<div id="document_info" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
  <div class="card datacard" style="justify-content:center">
    @include('loading_boxes')
    <h4>Loading...</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

$("div#tabs").on("click", "li", function() {
    $("div#" + $(this).data("id")).load($(this).data("url"));
});
</script>
```

My routes are like this:

```
Route::get('/{document}/getInfo', 'DocumentController@getInfo')->middleware('auth');
```

What the controller does:

```
public function getInfo(Request $request)
    {
        if(! Auth::user()->hasPermission('view-info'))
        {
            return view('generalerror', ['name'  => 'Info' , 'error' => "You can't view this data"]);
        }

        $document = Document::find(request('document'));
        $info = $document ->info ;
        if($info)
        {
            return view('document/info', ['info' =>$info]);
        }
        else
        {
            if(Auth::user()->hasPermission('store-info'))
            {
                return view('store_info_modal', ['Document' =>$document]);
            }
            return view('generalerror', ['name'  => 'Info' , 'error' => "This data has not been added yet"]);
        }
    }
```

When I open the modal and send the form I call this function in my controller:

```
public function storeInfo(StoreInfoRequest $request)
{   
  DocumentInfo::create([
  'info' => request('info'),
  'document' => request('document'),
  'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
  ]);
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Now the problem is**:
As you can see, I'm using a custom request class and it works fine. Anyway if the validators fails, the user is redirected on the main page. When I navigate to the info tab and reopen the modal clicking on the button, errros aren't shown up in the form since my modal is loaded from the controller.

Do you suggest a different implementation or do you have any solution for my problem?
Thanks in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: `redirect()->back();` uses the referrer, which is probably your main page. Specify the endpoint you wish to redirect your errors: `redirect()->route('yourroutehere')`

Comment: @adam this won't solve my problem. My modal is actually inside my main page and it's loaded by ajax only when the button is pressed. So I can't redirect to the modal.
I actually need to redirect the user to the main page but in some way I have to save that errors and load them to the modal when it's opened.